# how to propagate single transaction between multiple spring integration channels

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-transactions

In my application, I am using multiple spring integration channels. My requirement is the db operations in all channels should work as a single transaction.If the db operations in all channels are success, then only the transaction should commit or else all db operations should rollback.
Here is my code snippet:

MyFirstService.java

```
    @Transactional
    public class MyFirstService {

        @Resource
        private MyFirstRepository myFirstRepository;

        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "my-first-servie-input-channel",
                          outputChannel = "my-first-servie-output-channel")
        public String saveData(final MyEntity myEntity) {
             myFirstRepository.save(myEntity);
        }
    }
```

MySecondService.java

```
 @Transactional
 public class MySecondService {

    @Resource
    private MySecondRepository mySecondRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "my-first-servie-output-channel",
                      outputChannel = "my-Second-servie-output-channel")
    public String saveEntity(final MyTestEntity myTestEntity) {
         mySecondRepository.save(myTestEntity);
    }
}
```

spring-integration-context.xml

```
    <int:chain input-channel="transaction-inbound-channel" output-channel="my-first-servie-input-channel">
    </int:chain>
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter
            channel="transaction-inbound-channel"
            queue-names="sample.queue"
            concurrent-consumers="5"
            error-channel="failed-channel"
            connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
            mapped-request-headers="*" channel-transacted="true"/>

    <rabbit:connection-factory
            id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
            connection-factory="rcf"
            host="${spring.rabbitmq.host}"
            port="${spring.rabbitmq.port}"
            username="${spring.rabbitmq.username}"
            password="${spring.rabbitmq.password}"
            />
    <bean id="rcf" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${spring.rabbitmq.host}"/>
        <property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="10" />
    </bean>
```

So in the above code, if `mySecondRepository.save(myTestEntity);` fails, `myFirstRepository.save(myEntity);` should be rollback.

I didn't use `BarrierMessageHandler` anywhere in my application.
I added `@EnableTransactionManagement` to my configuration class.

Even I tried `channel-transacted="true"`, still no luck. Am I missing anything here?

I found the solution to propagate the single transaction between multiple methods of same service 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163569/how-to-manage-2-dao-methods-in-a-single-transaction 
But not between multiple channels. Can someone help me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure in your concern. The message channel operations are Java methods anyway. So, the same TX wrapping works here as well.

Only concern you should bare in mind that TX is thread-bounded and if you shift the message to a different thread, `ExecutorChannel`, `QueueChannel`, `PublishSubscribeChannel` with an `Executor` etc., the TX will be committed because you leave the holding thread.

So, if your `my-first-servie-output-channel` and `my-first-servie-output-channel` are `DirectChannel`s everything is OK and your TX will wrap the second repository call, too. Just because everything is done in the same thread.

There is a trick, of course, with the `BarrierMessageHandler`, which suspends one Thread, e.g. with transaction and wait for a trigger to release it and, therefore, commit TX.

**EDIT**

For propagation transaction from the MessageDriven Consumer to direct downstream flow you should supply transaction there.

The `channel-transacted` is something specific and really local to the channel to RabbitMQ. It fully unrelated to your repositories.

For this purpose the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` supports:

```
<xsd:attribute name="transaction-manager" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <xsd:documentation>
The PlatformTransactionManager to use when the Consumer receives the AMQP Message and the Listener is invoked.
                </xsd:documentation>
                <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                    <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager"/>
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

That `PlatformTransactionManager` can be any implementation which is sufficient for your downstream services.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding configuration xml and my comments to your reply. Could you please check.

Comment: Having a new info from you I provide some EDIT to my answer as well.

Comment: **For propagation transaction from the MessageDriven Consumer to direct downstream flow you should supply transaction there.**  I am very new to spring. Can you please elaborate how can I pass transaction-manager and start transaction.

Comment: That is a just a `transaction-manager` on the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`. Underneath container starts transaction for you automatically. Please, read more docs on the matter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-inbound-channel-adapter and an appropriate docs from Spring AMQP: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_transactions

Comment: **Thanks Artem, it worked when I added `transaction-manager="transactionManager" />` on the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`**. But it is restarting `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` after `TransactionSystemException`. Here is the log `[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO [] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer:`. **Is there any way to stop this**. Because it is continuously consuming the message, doing db operations and rolling back which is of no use and filling the memory with logs.

Comment: Well, that is fully expected that message will be requeued for the future consume on transaction rallback. You can consider to catch TX exception and rethrow it as a `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`. In this case your message will be dropped from the queue and the next listener cycle will go to the next message.

Comment: I did like this `public String saveEntity(final MyTestEntity myTestEntity)  throws AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException {                                         try {
         mySecondRepository.save(myTestEntity);                                     } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("exception");
    }`. But it is not working. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I don't know. Need to see full StackTrace. Maybe a new SO question?

Comment: Added new question with StackTrace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117051/simplemessagelistenercontainer-is-continuously-consuming-after-transactionsystem