# SimpleMessageListenerContainer is continuously consuming after TransactionSystemException

Tags: spring-integration, spring-transactions, spring-amqp

I don't want the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to continuously consume the messages when my Transaction marked as rollback.

I didn't add `listener-container` in my configuration file and trying to rethrow the `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`. It is not working.
Here is my codebase:

```
@Transactional
 public class MySecondService {

    @Resource
    private MySecondRepository mySecondRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "my-first-servie-output-channel",
                      outputChannel = "my-Second-servie-output-channel")
    public String saveEntity(final MyTestEntity myTestEntity) 
        throws AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException {
         try {
            mySecondRepository.save(myTestEntity);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("exception");
        }
    }
}
```

spring-integration-context.xml

```
<int:chain input-channel="transaction-inbound-channel" output-channel="my-first-servie-input-channel">
    </int:chain>
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter
            channel="transaction-inbound-channel"
            queue-names="sample.queue"
            concurrent-consumers="5"
            error-channel="failed-channel"
            connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
            mapped-request-headers="*" 
            transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <rabbit:connection-factory
            id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
            connection-factory="rcf"
            host="${spring.rabbitmq.host}"
            port="${spring.rabbitmq.port}"
            username="${spring.rabbitmq.username}"
            password="${spring.rabbitmq.password}"
            />
    <bean id="rcf" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${spring.rabbitmq.host}"/>
        <property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="10" />
    </bean>
```

This is the stack trace:

```
WARN [] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1062) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1203) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
2016-10-19 00:52:50,673 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO [] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-QBWGIY7co5vUpXwGDXDDBg=sample.queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://test@999.99.99.999:9999/,2), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

I don't want this to happen `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer`

Can some one help me to what else I need to add to rethrow the `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the flow.

If you are only invoking a single service, then don't add the transaction manager to the inbound channel adapter.

The transaction will start when the service is invoked; as long as the error flow on `failed-channel` does not throw an exception (or throws an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`) the message won't be requeued.

If you have multiple services that you want to participate in a single transaction, you can use an AOP advice to make `transaction-inbound-channel` transactional and the downstream flow will all run within that transaction.

Or, if you **never** want messages requeued, set `defaultRequeueRejected` to `false` on the inbound adapter's container (which you'll have to wire up as a `<bean/>`).

Comment: Fixed - `defaultRequeueRejected` is true by default; needs to the `false` to always reject.

Comment: You could try throwing an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` from the error flow; that should avoid the commit attempt.

Comment: Thanks Gary, when I added this to my `error-channel` it worked.                         `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "failed-channel")
    public void errorHandler(final Exception e) throws AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException {
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Exception.");
    } `.

Comment: I wanted to try the first option you mentioned. `defaultRequeueRejected` to false. But while creating bean to `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, I am getting this error `BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'listenerContainer' while setting constructor argument;nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory'`

Comment: Here is my configuration `<bean id="listenerContainer" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" value="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" value="transactionManager" />
        <property name="queueNames" value="${queue.credit.transaction}" />
        <property name="messageListener" value="messageListener" />
        <property name="defaultRequeueRejected" value="false" />
    </bean>`

Comment: Please don't put code/config in comments - as you can see, it's virtually unreadable - edit your question instead. The `connectionFactory` property needs to be a `ref` not a `value`.